Memory erros on Asrock N100M
I'm planning to build a new homeserver for nextcloud, paperless and so on. Therefore i bought/used the following hardware:

ASRock N100M mainboard
G.Skill AEGIS 16gb PC4-25600 F4-3200C16S-16GIS
Mushkin SSD
An old power supply

After setting the system, the system hang up several times and there where some segfault errors in syslog.
So i tried to track the error down:

Probably something wrong with the memory, so i installed memtest86 and run it.
-> Memory errors appeared.
To be sure that the memory is faulty, checked it in my desktop with memtest.
-> No errors
OK, maybe it is the power supply. Connected the PSU from my desktop with the N100M
-> Also memory errors

Conclusion of first round of troubleshooting: Mainboard must be faulty. So i send it back on warranty to the dealer.
After almost two months(horrible service), i got a new one(I checked SN) back. I changed some fan settings in BIOS, beside of that it is in the default settings and the newest version.
Just to be sure i ran memtest86 again. And there are again errors in memtest.
Than I found the page of Memory QVL at ASRock: https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/N100M/index.asp#Memory and my memory is not listed.
Ok so must be the wrong memory, i wasn't aware of Memory QVLs before.
So I bought a listed memory(Kingston KVR32N22S8/16) installed it and run memtest again. You probably know it, there are still errors.
No I've run out of ideas what is the problem here.
Should I test again with an different PSU? Or am I missing something else here?
Here is the last result of memtest:
memtest Result
The errors came up at the beginning, and then it run error free. But there were also runs where errors appeard later on.
EDIT: I ran memtest86 to produce some logs, the first two times it crashed pretty fast. The third time it ran for a while, produces 16 errors as the last run of memtest86+ but also crashed later on.
Log 1 (crashed after ~30s)
Log 2 (16 errors, as with memtest86+)

A memtest log could have added some information (check if you have one). But if a recommended RAM also fails, then I would return this board in your place.

I used memtest86+ before, which is not producing logs.
Now i ran memtest, the first two times it crashed pretty fast. The third time it produced 16 errors as the last run of memtest86+. The logs are attached above.
I already replaced the board once, do you really think i got two broken ones?

That seems unlikely, but the memory seems to have a small bad area. Your choice, but this board model seems problematic.
